# 4*4 reverse matrix code in matlab wich has variables

Tags: control, control-system, matlab, system, matrix

Here is the system of which I have found the state space equation. I need to get the transfer function. `[SI-A]` is a 4x4 matrix and it's so hard to get the reverse of it. What is the Matlab code of 4x4 reverse  matrix such that we do not have number just variables?

[image]

Comment: I think you're talking about the matrix inverse, and in MATLAB there is not in general an easy way to deal with symbolic algebra; try something like Mathematica instead. Or just do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab Symbolic toolbox can be used.

```matlab
syms s m1 mq b k1 kq

m = [s, -1, 0, 0;
  (kq+k1)/m1, s+b/m1, -kq/m1, -b/m1;
  sym(0), 0, s, -1;
  -kq/mq, -b/mq, (kq-k1)/mq, s+b/mq]

inv(m)
% OR
m\eye(4)
```

The result may not be the simplest possible expression though.

<sub>I tried the above code in Octave</sub>